# How to add UIInterfaceorientation Option in to .Plist file?

Tags: plist, uiinterfaceorientation

How can i add all for Orientation option in to my application's .plist file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only set the orientation for user interface when the iPhone App launches. In addition, you can change the orientation of your device:

> [[UIDevice currentDevice]
>   setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

and provide the appropriate response to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

> -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
>   {     return (interfaceOrientation ==
>   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); }

Comment: where is setOrientation declared?? orientation is a read-only property of UIDevice.